# Weak solution in Laplace operator is classical solution?

Tags: laplacian

Let $\Delta:D(\Delta)\subset L^2\to L^2$ where $D(\Delta)=\left\{u\in L^2:\Delta u\in L^2\right\}$. Let $f\in L^2$.

Let $u\in L^2$ a weak solution of $\Delta u=f$, then
$$(u,\Delta^*v)=(f,v),\quad \forall v\in D(\Delta^*)$$

Because $\Delta=\Delta^{*}$ ( self adjoint on $D(\Delta)$ maximal  domain) then
\begin{align}
(f,v)=(u,\Delta^*v)\\
=(u,\Delta v)\\
=(\Delta u,v)
\end{align}
Therefore,   $(f,v)=(\Delta u,v) \forall v\in D(\Delta)$ implies $\Delta u=f$?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: is $\Delta u=f?$

Comment: Yes, as $L^2$ functions (i.e. almost everywhere). This is not the same as being a classical solution.

Comment: but, why $(f,v)=(\Delta u,v),\forall v\in D(\Delta)$ implies that $\Delta u=f$? I can't see this. On the other hand, I have understood that a classical solution is a function $u\in L^2$ such that $\Delta u=f$.

Comment: Because in a complex hilbert space $\langle u,v\rangle=0$ for $v$ in a dense subspace implies $u=0$.

Comment: That is for this?
If $(h,k)=0$ for all $k\in K$  dense subspace of $H$ Hilbert, then $(h,k)=0$ for all $k\in H$. Proof. If $k\in H$ then exists $k_n\in K: k_n\to k$ in $H$. Then $|(h,k)|\leq |(h,k-k_n)|+|(h,k_n)|=|(h,k-k_n)|+0\leq \left\|h\right\|\left\| k-k_n\right\|\to 0 $when $\|h\|<\infty$. Why $\|h\|<\infty$?

Comment: $h$ is in the Hilbert space

Comment: excuse me maybe the basics but $h\in H$ implies $\left\|h\right\|<\infty $right? (sometimes the most basic questions are the ones that cost the most )

Comment: that's correct.